# How to force robot framework to pick robot files in sequential order?

Tags: robotframework

I have robot files in a folder (tests) as shown below:

```
tests
   1_robotfile1.robot
   2_robotfile2.robot
   3_robotfile3.robot
   4_robotfile4.robot
   5_robotfile5.robot
   6_robotfile6.robot
   7_robotfile7.robot
   8_robotfile8.robot
   9_robotfile9.robot
   10_robotfile10.robot
   11_robotfile11.robot
```

Now if I execute `'/root/users1/power$ pybot root/user1/tests'` command, robot files are running in following order:

```
tests
   1_robotfile1.robot
   10_robotfile10.robot
   11_robotfile11.robot
   2_robotfile2.robot
   3_robotfile3.robot
   4_robotfile4.robot
   5_robotfile5.robot
   6_robotfile6.robot
   7_robotfile7.robot
   8_robotfile8.robot
   9_robotfile9.robot
```

I want to force robot_framework to pick robot files in sequential order, like 1,2,3,4,5....

Do we have any option for this?

Comment: Do  you have the ability to rename your tests? Give them all three digit prefixes: 001_robotfile1.robot, 002_robotfile2.robot, 010_robotfile10.robot, ...

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks. After Renaming files, it is working as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the option of renaming your files, you just need to make sure that the prefix is sortable. For numbers, that means they should all have the same number of digits.

I recommend renaming your test cases to have three or four digits for the prefix:

```
001_robotfile1.robot
002_robotfile2.robot
003_robotfile3.robot
004_robotfile4.robot
005_robotfile5.robot
006_robotfile6.robot
007_robotfile7.robot
008_robotfile8.robot
009_robotfile9.robot
010_robotfile10.robot
011_robotfile11.robot
...
```

With that, they will sort in the order that you expect.

Answer (score 3):

Following @Emna answer, RF docs ( http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#execution-order ) provides some solution.

So what could you do:

1. rename all the files to have consecutive and computer numbering (001-test.robot instead of 1-test.robot). This may break any internal references to other files (resources), hard to add test in-between,error prone when execution order needs to be changed
2. you can tag it as Emna
3. idea from RF docs - write a script to create argument file which will keep ordering in proper way and use it as argument to robot execution. For 1000+ files it should not take longer than few seconds.
4. try to design tests to not be dependent from execution order, use suite setup instead.

good luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

Tag the tests as foo and bar so you can run each test separately:

```
pybot -i foo tests
```

or

```
pybot -i bar tests
```

and decide the order you want

```
pybot -i bar tests || pybot -i foo tests
```

Comment: The problem is, I have 100+ robot files, and 800+ test cases in these robot files. I think, it will be a time consuming job adding labels.